# Automate WhatsApp backup to Google Drive on demand /schedule

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, automation, macrodroid

Daily backup offered by app isn't an option since the device needs to be connected to Wifi at night time, which is a waste of battery. I have Titanium Backup schedule running but I would like to automate cloud backup too.

I am sure it can be done but I lack the knowledge to do it.

I am looking for a solution that preferably *does not* use gesture automation. But if that is the only way, I am fine with it.

**Setup**

- Oneplus-7, rooted with stock Android 10.
- EdXposed installed with Xposed EdgePro and Gravitybox.
- MacroDroid automation app is the preferred choice.

Note that "launch shortcut" action in MacroDroid requires fingerprint gesture accessibility permission, which is not possible with Oxygen OS. My guess is that one would need to use Xposed Edge Pro to trigger a bunch of actions.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: In Macrodroid, are you able to use the "UI Interaction" action?If yes, you can combine many "UI interaction" actions to open the Chat backup setting page of WhatApp, and then click the "Back up" buton.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: Thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't work. I am a big fan of MacroDroid but it can't really keep up with Android changes plus WhatsApp closed nature. I am looking for a more powerful, root solution that can work reliably. I think xposed edge pro is the right candidate

Comment: Just in case it helps, the activity name for this screen is `com.whatsapp/.gdrive.SettingsGoogleDrive`. However, the "Back Up" button doesn't trigger an external method that can be logged from the logcat, so I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks for the tip. Let me see if I can exploit it for a solution. Like I said in my previous comment, this activity is not exposed and hence the challenge

Comment: `shell am start -n com.whatsapp/.gdrive.SettingsGoogleDrive` with root permission did open the activity, just now I tried. And then I'm stuck...